# Where are the components listed?

Tags: untagged

I got my first Dice Throne box yesterday and want to do a component check. But I can't find the information on what's supposed to be included.

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

Each character has a list of their own components, on the back of their leaflet.

As the game is made up solely of character components, and a rulebook, that basically works.